# Show AppBar when showing dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, view, header, dialog

I have a custom `Dialog` and it works as it should but is there a way to fit the dialog to the screen?
So the `AppBar` could be seen (orange in the picture below). And there would be no black sides, meaning the dialog would basically cover the whole `view` but not the `AppBar`?

[image]

The reason why I even want to do this with the Dialog is because I have a form on one activity and when user wants to add something new to that form, he will have to open up a new form and I do not want to lose the data on the last form, so I thought just showing a dialog would be the simplest way to go about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the gravity of the custom dialog window as per below code.

```
// custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
                dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
                ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

                wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
                wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
                window.setAttributes(wlp);
```

Please Note :  This would only work if your contents are not overlapping the AppBar. If your contents are overlapping the AppBar, you would have to check for alternatives. 
I would suggest Fragments here.

Comment: This removes the black background but doesnt really put it in line with the AppBar.

Comment: The reason why I even want to do this with the Dialog is because I have a form on one activity and when user wants to add something new to that form, he will have to open up a new form and I do not want to lose the data on the last form, so I thought just showing a dialog would be the simplest way to go about that.